# How to use external js file in vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I would like to know how to use a jQuery library inside a vue file in Laravel 5.4

I want to use this library in my vue file:
[input mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

In my vue file I am creating a table and each row has a form with a date field with class 'date'.

With jQuery I will mask these fields with:
$('.date').mask('00/00/0000');

How can I import the library to vue and mask all these date fields?

The js file is in: public/js/jquery.mask.min.js

I tried:

```
var mask_script = require('/js/jquery.mask.min.js');
```

and:

```
var mask_script = require('js/jquery.mask.min.js');
```

And then:

```
export default {

        mounted: function () {
            this.loadData();
            $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
```

But I get this error on npm run dev:

Can't resolve js/jquery.mask.min.js

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the file from the actual path.

Try

```
// make sure the path is the actual path of jquery.mask.min.js
var mask_script = require('../../../public/js/jquery.mask.min.js');
```

I would then move `jquery.mask.min.js` to your `resources/assets/js/` folder somewhere because you are compiling it into you `app.js` file.

Comment: By the way, I'm new to Laravel, and I don't think I compile it into app.js.
I don't have it in the webpack.mix.js and not in app.js. Do I need to add it somewhere for it to be compiled? I don't fully understand this yet.

Comment: Can you post you directory structure as it relates to the javascript files.

Comment: mysite/public/js/jquery.mask.min.js
Vue component:
mysite/resources/assets/components

Comment: Try changing the path to `var mask_script = require('../../../public/js/jquery.mask.min.js');`

Comment: Thx, didn't help either.

Comment: Ok, I copied the js file to resources/assets/js. And I'm calling it like this: require('./../jquery.mask.min.js'); Now there is no error, but the input fields don't get the mask. So this: mounted: function () {
            this.loadData();
            $('.date').mask('00/00/0000'); 
Does not do anything

Comment: Use your developer tools and in the console in the browser type `$('.date').mask('00/00/0000');` and see if it applies the mask. If so you need to wrap `$('.date').mask('00/00/0000');` with `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thx. I created a component instead, now I'm struggling with the prop. Will post a new question

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/) bootstrap template in vue. It requires [holder](http://holderjs.com/) libaray to show thumbnail icons.
so I have created a folder in **resources/js/scripts** where I saved `holder.min.js` and then I called in vue page like this.

**Folder structure of laravel 5.7**

```
     resources
          \js
           |components
           |views (I have created this folder to save vue pages)
                 \inventory(folder)
                                 \Index.vue
           |scripts
                   \holder.min.js
```

**In Index.vue View located at resources/js/inventory/Index**

```
<script> require('../../scripts/holder.min.js')</script>

first ../ will take it to views directory from inventory
second ../ will take it to main js directory where scripts folder is located
```

and it worked without any issue.